# How to use Div function

Tags: delphi, division

It pops up with an error:

```
procedure TForm1.btnDivideClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dNum1, dNum2, dTotal :double;
begin

  dNum1 := strtofloat (edtNum1.text);
  dNum2 := strtofloat (edtNum2.text);

  dTotal := dNum1 div dNum2;    

  memOutput.Lines.Add('Total: ' + floattostr (dTotal));    
end;
```

Comment: div is for use with integers. Use **dTotal := dNum1 / dNum2**

Comment: `div` is an operator, **not** a function

Comment: In the future, please don't write "it pops up with an error" without quoting the actual error message!

Comment: In addition, I am a bit surprised that you didn't find the answer to your question by reading [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Arithmetic_Operators) about the `div` operator!

Answer (score 4):

`Div` is the integer division operator. The floating-point division operator is `/` instead:

```
procedure TForm1.btnDivideClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dNum1, dNum2, dTotal :double;
begin
  dNum1  := strtofloat(edtNum1.text);
  dNum2  := strtofloat(edtNum2.text);
  dTotal := dNum1 / dNum2;    
  memOutput.Lines.Add('Total: ' + floattostr(dTotal));    
end;
```